# Boost hana size of tuple type

Tags: c++, tuples, boost-hana

I know how I can obtain the size of an tuple object in `boost::hana` like this:

```
auto tupleSize = hana::size(hana::make_tuple(1,2,3))
```

But what about the size of a tuple type? The stl provides allready the following tuple type trait:

```
constexpr size_t tupleSize = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<int, int, int>>::value;
```

Is there a similar type trait within hana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none. My guess is that you are misusing Hana here, or that there's an equivalent way to do what you're trying to achieve without having to call `size` on a tuple type. But I can't know for sure without seeing the rest of your code, so take this with a grain of salt.

The way you could workaround the lack of a `tuple_size`-like metafunction is by using `declval`. You could write:

```
constexpr size_t tupleSize = decltype(
    hana::size(std::declval<hana::tuple<T...>>())
)::value;
```

Note that depending on the context in which you have to call this, it might even be possible to use `sizeof...(T)` if you have this information.

Comment: Maybe I misuse hana, but what I really want to achieve is the size of two parameter packs `...T_A` and `...T_B` and then substract its sizes. The difference is then used as template argument for a class.